# Load, compile and run Eclipse project with a bash file

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, build

Given an hypothetical Eclipse project located in :

C:\user\john.doe\workspace\myProject

Is it possible with a simple bash script (or else) to:

- Open Eclipse
- Compile the project
- Run the project
- Possibly do this for multiple projects at the same time

with a simple click?

I'm working on an application and I currently have several modules all with their own suit of unit tests in a separate project. I would like to make it as effortless as possible to run every single test benches when changes are made by me and others so the code doesn't rot because it takes too much time to run the 10+ test projects.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 for C projects.

Comment: Why don't you use something like Maven (http://maven.apache.org/) to build and test the projects via command line?

Comment: Why do you want to use an IDE for unit testing?